# Less generates multiple CSS files

Tags: css, less

I have a `less` file which requests 7 external `stylesheet` and `script` for `single` page. I have attached screenshot for more details.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbmbz.png)

Code as below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="JS/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="JS/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" href="Images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/CubeCss/CubeMetropolis.less" />
    <script src="JS/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {


             if (document.getElementById("SelectedTheme").value == 'Office2010Black') {
                 less.modifyVars
                 ({
                     '@baseColor': "#828282",
                     '@baseActiveColor': "#f2f5f8",
                     '@baseBg': "#f2f5f8"
                 });
             }

             if (document.getElementById("SelectedTheme").value == 'Youthful') {
                 less.modifyVars
                ({
                    '@baseColor': "#009688",
                    '@baseActiveColor': "#68d2c8",
                    '@baseBg': "#ecfffd"
                });
             }
             else if (document.getElementById("SelectedTheme").value == 'Metropolis') {
                 less.modifyVars({

                     '@baseColor': "#EA9B41",
                     '@baseActiveColor': "#ffa400",
                     '@baseBg': "#fff1d9"

                 });


             }
             else if (document.getElementById("SelectedTheme").value == 'PlasticBlue') {
                 less.modifyVars({
                     '@baseColor': "#168ED7",
                     '@baseActiveColor': "#52beff",
                     '@baseBg': "#daf1ff"

                 });
             }

             else if (document.getElementById("SelectedTheme").value == 'RedWine') {
                 less.modifyVars({
                     '@baseColor': "#ec4b4b",
                     '@baseActiveColor': "#d26469",
                     '@baseBg': "#f9e7e7"

                 });
             }

             else if (document.getElementById("SelectedTheme").value == 'Office2003Olive') {
                 less.modifyVars({
                     '@baseColor': "#8da02a",
                     '@baseActiveColor': "#cfe465",
                     '@baseBg': "#f3f7e1"

                 });
             }

         });
    </script>
</head>
```

I need help to assign variable value before loading the page, now it fluctuates at first and shows default color (i.e. black) then changes to theme selected color.

My CSS Code:

```
@baseColor:~'';
.dxpnl-btnSelected.dxpnl-btnPressed .dxWeb_pnlExpandArrowTop_Metropolis
{
    background-color: @baseColor;
}
```

Where should use`.modifyVars` so it won't fluctuate?

Comment: Why you have 2x jQuery lib? What library to generate LESS you use and why not use pre-processor that already saves your LESS file as CSS and you just include `.css` itself?

Comment: @Justinas I didn't get you could you please share eg. exactly what needs to be done.

Comment: Use some tool like lessc (http://lesscss.org/usage/) or Koala (http://koala-app.com/) to generate CSS file instead of loading JS, than do LESS compile, and only than receive CSS styles